# How to know about get or post request from server

Tags: python, django

i want to identify GET or POST request from particular client in django using programming so i could do same stuff if i get request from that particular client. what is the way to do that??

Here i want to perform some operation if a i get request from client....not from any client only particular client.....

Comment: What?! Please re-arrange your question

Comment: Are you trying to determine if a request is a GET or a POST?

Comment: @Brandon i edited my question ...please recheck and let me know...

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type of request in django as request.method which will return the type of request either GET or POST.

Comment: what if i want to know who requested .... i mean address of user who requested...

Comment: You should consider the django docs about the basic concepts of request and user. While you can get the user information from the request object as request.user.

Answer (score 0):

The information you're looking for is part of the `request.META` dictionary:

```
request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
```

Answer (score 0):

I got solution

```
request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
```